# 403 FORBIDDEN APACHE django

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-403

Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.12 mod_wsgi/4.9.4 Python/3.11 Server at localhost Port 80

I am trying to run my django project on my windows machine.. in apache this the configuration i have added in httpd.conf file . i have installed mod_wsgi. and everything is correct . but iam getting the error error 403 forbidden
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/Python311/python311.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Program Files/Python311/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Program Files/Python311"

WSGIScriptAlias / "D:\TeNWyn@tenwyn.media.dev\TENWYN\TENWYN\wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "D:\TeNWyn@tenwyn.media.dev\TENWYN"

<Directory "D:\TeNWyn@tenwyn.media.dev\TENWYN\TENWYN">

Require all granted

Alias /static "D:\TeNWyn@tenwyn.media.dev\TENWYN\TENWYNMEDIA\static"
<Directory "D:\TeNWyn@tenwyn.media.dev\TENWYN\TENWYNMEDIA\static">
Require all granted